# How much energy is wasted by plugging a laptop wall charger into an automotive inverter

Tags: power, inverter, power-consumption

I've been plugging my laptop into an inverter, from my van battery, the adapter is 60W, but it seems strange to convert DC to AC and then back to DC again. The inverter is 700W. How much energy am I wasting by converting from DC ti AC and back.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know about your case without specific knowledge of your inverter.  You therefore need to look up the efficiency of your particular inverter at that particular operating point, or measure it.  A 700 W inverter may be reasonably efficient at 650 W, but could be horribly inefficient at 50 W, for example.

Actually, you should measure the overall efficiency from car battery to DC output of the charger, then compare that to a similar setup that works directly from the car battery.  That's the only way to know for sure.

Comment: yeah, I'm just looking for a ballpark, I think the one I have is %85 efficiency, but I'm also looking at how much is lost by converting it back to DC, the iPhone transformers get really hot, assuming they are not super efficient.